# Finding min max of nested list and using index to return corresponding values in other nested list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two nested lists of numbers `var1` and `var2`.

```
var1 = [[1, 2206], [578, 619]]
var2 = [[122498, 124673], [101182, 101223]]
```

I want to find the highest and lowest values from var1 and use the indexes of these values to return values from the same index in var 2, `122498` and `124673`.

So far I have found the location of the highest and lowest values in var1 using

```
var1a = np.array(var1)
var1maxloc = str(np.unravel_index(np.argmax(var1a), var1a.shape))
var1minloc = str(np.unravel_index(np.argmin(var1a), var1a.shape))
```

However I am uncertain how to proceed

I manipulated output so it would be same for index in list but can't work out how to use

```
var1minloc.replace(")", "]").replace(", ", "][").replace("(", "[")
var1maxloc.replace(")", "]").replace(", ", "][").replace("(", "[")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but no need to do anything with strings:

```
>>> var1 = np.array([[1, 2206], [578, 619]])
>>> var2 = np.array([[122498, 124673], [101182, 101223]])
>>> min_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(var1), var1.shape)
>>> max_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(var1), var1.shape)
>>> var2[min_idx]
122498
>>> var2[max_idx]
124673
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to flatten both arrays before calculating min / max index and retrieving the values, assuming the two arrays always have the same shape:

```
min_max = [np.argmin(var1.ravel()), np.argmax(var1.ravel())]
var2.ravel()[min_max]    
# [122498 124673]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a boolean mask:

```
var1 = np.array([[1, 2206], [578, 619]])
var2 = np.array([[122498, 124673], [101182, 101223]])

mask = np.logical_or(var1 == np.min(var1), var1 == np.max(var1))
var2[mask]
```

Output:

```
array([122498, 124673])
```